# jQuery not working in IE9. addEventListener Issue

Tags: jquery

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to jQuery and have modified an upload script that I found on line. It is doing everything I expect in Chrome. I tested it in Internet Explorer and it is giving the following error:-

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' 
>   upload.js, line 21 character 3.

I have done some research and it seems addEventListener isn't supported in IE. Could any one help me in tweaking the code to get it working please. Thanks very much.

```
(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("images"),
        oID = $('#oID').val(),
        formdata = false;

    function showUploadedItem(source) {
        var list = document.getElementById("image-list"),
            li = document.createElement("li"),
            img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = source;
        li.appendChild(img);
        list.appendChild(li);
    }

    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();
        document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
    }

    input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Uploading . . ."
        var i = 0,
            len = this.files.length,
            img, reader, file;

        for (; i < len; i++) {
            file = this.files[i];

            if ( !! file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                if (window.FileReader) {
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                        showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
                if (formdata) {
                    formdata.append("images[]", file);
                }
            }
        }

        formdata.append("oID", oID);
        if (formdata) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
                }
            });
        }
    }, false);
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$(input).change(function (evt) {
    // your code
});
```

or -

```
$("#images").change(function (evt) {
    // your code
});
```

You are using jQuery, right? If this is the case, then change your code like this -

1. Rather than selecting element using `document.getElementById(id)`, try selecting them by using `$("#your_id_string")`.
2. Rather than hiding element using `document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";`, try `$("#your_id_string").hide()`
3. Rather than changing html text using `document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "text"`, try using `$("#response").html("text")`

and your code will be much cleaner.

Also, notice that you have error in your code. Your anonymous function declaration is not correct. Try this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("images"),
    oID = $('#oID').val(),
    formdata = false;

    // rest of your code.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yes jQuery. The first two suggestions didn't work. I will try your further 3 suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @GaryWaudby: You need to put only your current function body inside the `document.ready`. I have edited again. Please check.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Cant vote you up as not enough reputation +1

Comment: @GaryWaudby: Now you probably have enough reputation :-). If a question is worth answering, then it's worth a +1, so I gave you one.

Comment: @GaryWaudby please can you share your code finally what the result you made. I am trying to follow this things.